# Split, group and mean: computation with arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, mean, correctness

`A` is a given `N x R xT` array. I must split it horizontally to `N` sub-arrays of size `L x M` and then group each `z` together in an array `K` and take a mean.

***For Example:*** `A` is the array  rand(N,R,T)= rand( 16, 3 ,3); Now I am going to split it:

```
A=rand( 16, 3 ,3)   :   A(1,:,:), A(2,:,:), A(3,:,:), A(4,:,:), ... , A(16,:,:).
```

I have 16 slices.

```
B_1=A(1,:,:);  B_2=A(2,:,:);   B_3=A(3,:,:);  ... ; B_16=A(16,:,:);
```

The next step is grouping together every 3 ( for example).

Now I am going create `K_i` as :

```
K_1(1,:,:)=B_1;
K_1(2,:,:)=B_2;
K_1(3,:,:)=B_3;

...
K_8(1,:,:)=B_14;
K_8(2,:,:)=B_15;
K_8(3,:,:)=B_16;
```

The average array is found as:

```
C_1=[B_1 + B_2 +  B_3]/3
...

C_8= [ B_14 + B_15 + B_16] /3
```

I have implemented it as:

```
A_reshape = reshape(squeeze(A), size(A,2), size(A,3),2, []);
mean_of_all_slices = permute(mean(A_reshape , 3), [1 2 4 3]);
```

`Question 1` **I have checked by hand. It gives me a wrong result. How to fix it?**  [SOLVED]

**EDIT 2**  I need to simulate the following computation:

take a product each slice of the array `K_i` with another array `P_p`: It means:

```
for `K_1` is given `P_1`): `B_1 * P_1` , `B_2 * P_1`, `B_3 * P_1`

...
for `K_8` is given `P_8`): `B_14 * P_8` , `B_15 * P_8`, `B_16 * P_8`
```

I have solved!!!

Comment: Think of how you can create an input array that wil clearly show that the result is what you expect. Then make that array and throw your code at it to see if it behaves as expected.

Comment: I don't understand how this works: if `K_2 = [ B_4 B_5 B_6]` then `K_3 = [ B_7 B_8 B_9]` ... `K_6 = [ B_16 B_17 B_18]` and `K_8 = [ B_22 B_23 B_24]` **!!** Please clarify this.

Comment: @Dev-iL I have solved, thank you

Answer (score 2):

> **Disclaimer**: this answers a previous version of the question.

In cases such as this I would suggest relying on built-ins, which have a predictable behavior. In your case, this would be [`movmean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmean.html) (introduced in R2016a):

```matlab
WIN_SZ = 2;  % Window size for averaging
AVG_DIM = 1; % Dimension for averaging
tmp = movmean(A, WIN_SZ , AVG_DIM ,'Endpoints', 'discard');
C = tmp(1:WINDOW_SZ:end, :, :); % This only selects A1+A2, A3+A4 etc.
```

If your MATLAB is a bit older, this can also be done using convolution ([`convn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html), introduced before R2006):

```matlab
WIN_SZ = 3;
tmp = convn(A, ones(WIN_SZ ,1)./WIN_SZ, 'valid'); % Shorter than A in dim1 by (WIN_SZ-1)
C = tmp(1:WINDOW_SZ:end, :, :); % dim1 size is: ceil((size(A,1)-(WIN_SZ-1))/3)
```

---

BTW, the step where you create `B` from slices of `A` can be done using

```
B = num2cell(A,[2,3]); % yields a 16x1 cell array of 1x3x3 double arrays
```

Comment: I am using R2015 and have tried the line with `conv`. It doesn't work. If `A=rand(12,4,4)`, `C` =11 x 4 x 4